# XmlHttpRequest origin header is null in webkit

Tags: webkit, xmlhttprequest, cors, same-origin-policy

I am trying to integrate 2 webapps to let one (new one) send a url to another (old one) that it will load into a text area.  The URL is actually to a file in S3 (with the multiple redirects that come with that) and I am trying to do this in the receiver using an XMLHTTPRequest like so;

```
    var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
    client.withCredentials = true;
    client.open('GET', geneIdFileUrl, true );
    client.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "text/plain");
    client.onreadystatechange = function() {
      document.getElementById('geneList').value = client.responseText;
    }
    client.send();
```

This is fine in firefox but in webkit browsers (chrome, safari) the request is being sent out with the request header

```
    Origin  null
```

instead of the real origin of the page making the request.  The get from S3 is coming as a ContentDisposition attachment so I can't just dump it into an iframe and read the contents from there.

Why do the webkit browsers not set the origin properly and is it possible to coecre them into doing so?

Comment: Have you found any solution on this yet?